# Copying an object to another by key(s) compare

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to copy a object to another by comparing it's key. according to me the key can be nested any of the object node. still I am require to copy them in another object by just comparing their `key`.

they object key in any level in the object tree.

Is this possible?

here is my try:

```
var extend = function (original, context, key) {
  for (key in context)
    if (context.hasOwnProperty(key))
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(context[key]) === '[object Object]')
        original[key] = extend(original[key] || {}, context[key]);
      else
        original[key] = context[key];
  return original;
};

var firstObject = {
    key1 : 'ar',
    key2 : 'value2',
    address:{
    "street" : "D15 Road"
    "sub":{"name":"Stockoverflow"}
    }
};

var secondObject = {
    name:"",
    street:"",
    key3 : 'value3',
    key4 : 'value4'
};
var x = extend(secondObject, firstObject )
console.log( 'extend', x );
```

In my above try, still the `street:"",` `name:""` not updated.

Comment: Your `extend` has a `key` argument, which is used multiple times, but the function is never called with a third argument, it looks like...? Perhaps you meant to have only two arguments and use `for (const key in context)`

Comment: So basically, if it finds `street` anywhere within the second object, it'll set the value of the first to that, correct?

Comment: Yes,  samanime - is right. Looking for shortest way and clear code too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
const source = {
  key1: 'a',
  common1: 'value1',
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        common2: 'value2'
      }
    }
  }
};

const dest = {
  key2: 'b',
  common1: null,
  common2: null
};

function extend(dest, source) {
  Object.entries(source).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      extend(dest, value);
    } else if (dest.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      dest[key] = value;
    }
  });
}

extend(dest, source);
console.log(dest);
```

Basically, looping through them you only have two options: it's an object or it's key matches.

If it is an object, we just recursively call `extend`. If it's key matches, then we set the value.

If you want to be able to do this with objects as values (i.e., `common1` could be an object instead of a primitive), just switch the two in the `if` statement.